# Django TemplateDoesNotExist Exception

Tags: django, templates, exception

I was trying to use django-endless-pagination [twitter pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html), but Django is throwing and exception and I'm having trouble debugging it.

After creating these templates:

search_results.html:

```
<h2>Entries:</h2>
{% include page_template %}
```

results.html:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {# your code to show the entry #}
{% endfor %}
```

I added them to my projects template directory.  I then create this view:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:  #Need to add input variable to html code
        q = request.GET['q']
        if q:
            stuff = Stuff.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
            template = "search_results.html"
            page_template = "results.html"
            if request.is_ajax():
                template = page_template
            return render_to_response(template, locals())
    return render_to_response('search_page.html')
```

When I go to the results url I get:
**Exception Type:** TemplateDoesNotExist

**Exception Location:** /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138

**Template-loader postmortem**

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/Users/some_account/Dropbox/code/project/project/html (File exists)
/Users/some_account/Dropbox/code/project/project/course_database/templates (File exists)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Users/some_account/Dropbox/code/project/project/course_database/templates (File exists)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/endless_pagination/templates (File exists)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates (File exists)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates (File exists)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/templates (File exists)

And the error during template loading is located at a line that includes: `{% include page_template %}`

Why would I be getting this exception, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your search_results.html page, you have `{% include page_template %}`, and I assume you are using locals() to pass it into the template. Can you output it on the template to verify what `page_template`'s value is? Put `{{ page_template }}` in place of `{% include page_template %}` to verify it is getting the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie to `Django` and I put the installed app direction in "template area" and get this error.

double check why you put the route in template,
both template and installed app list start with `djang.something`, but they are different.